# A problem on equivalent metrics and equivalence classes

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $ X $ be a non empty set and $ \tau= \{d\mid d$ is a metric on $X\}$  Define the relation  $\sim $ on $\tau$ by $ d \sim d' $ iff $ d $ and $ d'$ are equivalent metrics on $X$. Show that $\sim $ is an equivalence relation on $\tau $. Identify equivalence classes.

I could prove that it is an equivalence relation but I couldn't understand how to identify equivalence classes? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What if X is a space that is not metrizable? Then $\tau$ would be empty. Perhaps you are assuming X to be a metric space...

Comment: Yes I was considering the metric spaces

Comment: @GautamShenoy $X$ is just a set and any set allows a metric.

Comment: Which of the many concepts of equivalence of metrics are you using?

Comment: @ChrisEagle The definition given was two $d_1 d_2 $ metrics are equivalent if $\tau_1 $= $\tau_2$ where $\tau_1$= {$ G \subseteq X | G $is $d_1$ open} and $\tau_2 $={$ G \subseteq X $| G is $d_2 open$}

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a metric space,you can determine equivalent classes of this equivalent relation with metrizable topologies on $X$ Because,equivalent metrics generate same topology on $X$.

Comment: Can you please show a way of finding an equivalence class?

Comment: $X$ is just a set, neither a metric space nor any other sort of topological space. But yes, one can identify the equivalence classes with the metrizable topologies on $X$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you tell me how to find the equivalence classes in this please?